# Exporting all content of ListView as Png

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal, xamarin.uwp

I'm building an app that contains a kanban board which I would like to export as a PNG image. The board consists of a ListView of the card status' (To-do, doing, etc ) and each one of those is ListView containing the cards of the same status.
I'm already able to export the board as an image using a RenderTargetBitmap, however, the output will have the content that's in view. Instead, I want to have an image containing all the cards.

I honestly don't think it's that simple since only the visible cards are rendered on the page in the first place but I want to know if there's a different approach to this problem.

This is how an exported board would look at the moment
[image: currently exported board]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exporting all content of ListView as Png

Currently, UWP has no such api to get long screenshot. I'm afraid you can't approach with [`RenderTargetBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap?view=winrt-20348) class.

And we can imagine, if we could scale current view, and make all content show in the current window, then we could get the complete screenshot. So we could try to place above all in [`ScrollViewer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer?view=winrt-20348) and set it ZoomMode as enable. Just call [`ChangeView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.changeview?view=winrt-20348) method to give it a appropriate ZoomFactor value to display all the content in visible place .

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" >
    <Grid>
        <ListView>
```

Please note this way will disable the listview's ui virtualization. and if we scaled scrollviewer, the effective pixels of the current windows will be lower.

And you do want this feature, please feel free post your requirement with windows feedback hub.

Comment: It's a shame though I understand why it wouldn't be a feature. Zooming works but the output image will most likely look terrible if there's a lot of content to render. The only other way I can think of, is generating the controls in code inside a loop, render each one in a separate image, then mergin them all which sounds kind of a stretch tbh.